# Insert pandas data frame into Postgres

Tags: python, django, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which I want to insert it into my Postgres database in my Django project.

The data frame has 5 columns and the Database table has 6 columns and moreover, the data frame columns and DB columns order are not the same.

So, before merging both, do I have to make sure that the order of the columns is the same in both the data frame and DB table? and how pls suggest how do I handle the missing column

Comment: if you insert into the table less columns then there actually are, and you have loose constraints (columns can be nullable) then the other columns should just get NULL inserted into them. best method I think would be `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` --> `io.StringIO` --> `psycopg2.cursor.copy_to`

Comment: @aws_apprentice what about the order of the columns, does it matter? and I did not get what you said in the last line. can you please elaborate

Comment: the last line is the tools you can use to achieve this, and yes your data should be organized in the same way your insert query is

Answer (score 9):

If **dataframe has column names same as column names in database**, you can **insert df directly into database** table using [`dataframe.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method with the help of `sqlalchemy` for connection:

```
from myapp.models import Bob
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from django.conf import settings

db_connection_url = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
    settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'],
    settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'],
    settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'],
    settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT'],
    settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'],
)

engine = create_engine(db_connection_url)

df.to_sql(Bob._meta.db_table, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Missing column will be empty (or database will set default value if it defined at database level, not django level), or you can add missing column to dataframe with required value.

Answer (score 3):

Just do an Explicit Insert ...

If your table has columns in the order of A,B,C,D,E

But your Pandas has them in the order of D,C,B,A (Note no Column E)

Just generate an SQL Insert like (Note I have no Column E)

```
   insert into <TABLE> (D,C,B,A) values (row_iterator.D,row_iterator.C,...)
```

For the Column E - the best and simplest solution is have a default value in the Db Definition ....

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Bob (
    A int NOT NULL,
    B int NOT NULL,
    C int NOT NULL,
    D int NOT NULL,
    E int DEFAULT 42
);
```

Hope that helps