# Copying CSV to PostgreSQL database using Psycopg3 in Python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, copy, psycopg3

I'm having a little difficulty understanding appropriate syntax for the `psycopg3` library in Python. I'm trying to copy the contents of a .csv file into my database. [The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) indicates `copy` should be written as follows:

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
    [ WHERE condition ]
```

so I wrote my python statement as follows:

```
import psycopg


with psycopg.connect('dbname=ideatest user=postgres password=password') as conn: 
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            mock_idea_info = open(r'C:\dir\filename.csv')
            cur.copy('public.ideastorage FROM C:\dir\filename.csv;')

print('Copy successful.')
```

The problem is that the script prints 'Copy successful,' but does not insert the data into the db. No error messages are generated. I've duplicated the \ characters in the file path, so that isn't the issue. I've been looking around for solutions and possible troubleshooting methods, but have yet to find anything I understand that seems relevant.

Additionally, is there any way I might be able to pass `mock_idea_info` directly into the `copy` statement?

Any assistance would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert pandas data frame into Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59613267/insert-pandas-data-frame-into-postgres)

Comment: Well. I'm sure that solution works. I was trying to avoid using another library to manage SQL statements. In that solution, it seems that SQLAlchemy was used. I was specifically looking for a psycopg solution. I could use some other library with simpler functionality, but feel like that's kind of sloppy coding.

Comment: See here [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#copy), the 'Copying block-by-block' example.

Comment: I had that exact page open when I wrote the question, but I don't fully understand it. My python-fu isn't that strong. 

The statement with open('data', 'r') seems to open the file based on the filename. I see that. And the while loop seems to write values iteratively to the database until the document is finished being read. 

But this line : `with cursor.copy("COPY data FROM STDIN") as copy` gives me trouble. 

it seems like the entire file is being converted into an object that is then stored and (somehow) broken down for column-based storage in the db. Is that correct?

Comment: See my answer for examples. I'm still figuring out `psycopg3` so the answer probably needs refining, but I think it will serve as a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Copy from](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#copy):

```
cat data.out 
1       2
2       1

\d csv_test 
              Table "public.csv_test"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 col1   | integer |           |          | 
 col2   | integer |           |          | 


with open("data.out", "r") as f:
     with cur.copy("COPY csv_test FROM STDIN") as copy:
         while data := f.read(100):
            copy.write(data)
con.commit()

select * from csv_test ;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 |    2
    2 |    1

--Add format options
cat data.out 
1,2
2,1
with open("data.out", "r") as f:
     with cur.copy("COPY csv_test FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)" ) as copy:
         while data := f.read(100):
            copy.write(data)
con.commit()

select * from csv_test ;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 |    2
    2 |    1
    1 |    2
    2 |    1
```

Above adapted from examples in link. This `while data := f.read(100)` uses the walrus(`:=`) only available in Python 3.8+

Comment: Perfect response. Psycopg3 docuement is not clear about being able to add WITH part. That's why I was in trouble too. Thank you Adrian. What is the unit of that 100? Byte, Char?

Comment: For `read(size)` see [7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files): "...call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data .." [...] "Otherwise, at most size characters (in text mode) or size bytes (in binary mode) are read ..."

Answer (score -1):

I do not see that you make a commit to persist the data in your data base after the input. Try to add this:

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, when used with the `with` keyword as context, `conn.commit()` is automatically executed upon close. 

But I tried it anyway, and that did not affect the output.

Comment: can you explain what this does ?

Answer (score -1):

You probably should include the `with (format csv)` clause (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or explicitly specify the quote and delimiter characters.

Comment: The psycopg3 documentation specifically says to leave those clauses alone. It crossed my mind. I think psycopg3 has a unique way of doing things.

Comment: When copying block-by-block, as you are with a file, the psycopg3 documentation says "In this case you can use any COPY option and format, as long as the input data is compatible."

Comment: When writing/reading row by row you cannot use the additional clauses. As was pointed out when writing/reading by block you can use them.